Something makes a chirping nose when turning left or going straight, but not right
So I've got a 2018 Wrangler JK that for the past few weeks has been having a noise issue I can't figure out.
A few weeks ago, only in the mornings, I started to notice a chirping noise that occurred when I was turning left. At the time, it only happened early morning, and only while turning about 15+ degrees left. Since then it has progressed to occur anywhere between about 5 degrees right and anywhere left of that, but disappears on right turns. Additionally, the chirp is now occurring later in the day, although less present than in the mornings.
From what I can tell, the noise is coming from somewhere in the steering column area of the dash, on the cabin side of the firewall. I've stuck my head out the window while it occurs and only ever hear noise coming from inside, outside is just wind and road nose as far as I can detect.
The chirp always has the same frequency between chips, pitch, and for a given drive the same volume. Drives later in the day are generally lower volume chirps, with the same frequency and pitch as the morning.
Here's a 5s video of it happening: https://photos.app.goo.gl/Feeo1FQDJjd8RT4h6
I'm guessing the difference in temperature from early morning (I'm generally on my way to work around 6am, so right at sun up) to lunch sitting in an uncovered parking lot creates some sort of thermal expansion that loosens up whatever's rubbing just enough for it to not chirp.
A few specifics I've noticed since it's started:

it occurs only while in motion, and while I can't say I've heard it in reverse, I can't rule it out either as most of my daily route requires reversing with the wheel to the right
it occurs while accelerating, coasting (foot off pedals), and braking with no noticable change in behavior between the three states
speed does not seem to affect it, as it occurs and sounds nearly identical at 5mph from a dead stop to 70mph on the highway
a large bump will generally cause a few seconds of chirping, then it goes quiet
a lightly bumpy road will cause almost constant chirping while in the problematic angular rotations of the steering wheel
however, it can also happen on dead flat roads, though left turns on well maintained roads cause it far more often than going straight

I'm at a loss, I just can't seem to pinpoint this one. Anyone have a clue?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If the steering wheel is perfectly still, does the noise occur (vehicle moving or stationary)? IOW, is it usually only when turning the wheel? Also, I hear it occuring when you're turning the wheel back to straight from a left hand turn. Do you hear it turning the wheel left from a right hand turn?

You've checked your power steering fluid level?

Yes, Power Steering fluid appears to be good.

Apologies, completely missed the first comment as the first sentence made me think it was an auto-reply for first time posters, my bad. It doesn't seem to be a function of actually turning the steering. With "up" being 0deg, it occurs anywhere from about 5deg right to full left turn, regardless of the direction the steering is being rotated. So, rotating the wheel from 90 left to 45 left (clockwise), it sounds the same as rotating from 45 left to 90 left (counterclockwise), which sounds the same as it does when holding it stable as I physically can at 0.
